# Finding the zero vector of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $(V, \oplus, \odot)$ be a vector space with additive identity $0_{V}$. If $$(\exists z\in V)(\forall u\in V)\,\, \colon\quad u\oplus z = z\oplus u = u,$$ then $z=0_{V}$.

Take $u\in V$, then the above implies there is a $z\in V$ such that $$u\oplus z = z\oplus u= u.$$ Now I don't really have any idea how to make logical steps to the conclusion that $z=0_{V}$. Any tips?

Comment: It's a theorem from mathematical logic that $\,\,\exists z \forall u P(z,u) \rightarrow\forall u  \exists z P(z,u) $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity holds *for every* $u\in V$; in particular for $u=0_V$, so
$$
0_V=0_V\oplus z
$$
But, by the property of $0_V$, $0_V\oplus z=z$. Therefore $z=0_V$.